# Magento Configurable Product Save Not Working

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, save

On configurable product creation, when I hit the save button, I'm getting the error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getStoreLabel() on a non-object in /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Configurable/Attribute.php on line 79
```

I've disabled all the local modules and still the error is coming. Simple products are saving correctly. Could anyone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: Have you deleted any magento attributes? there is still some code trying to get attribute label.

Comment: Using disable local modules in `local.xml` *ONLY* disables `app/code/local`, `app/code/community` still loads, easiest option, rename community and determine if its a core issue or not.

Comment: I am getting the same issue and I am sure it is a core issue. How did you resolve this @blakcaps?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you flush the config cache after disabling your local modules. Also check if any of your modules is extending the product Model. For more info on how to debug check: [Fundamentals for debugging a Magento store](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store)

Comment: @brentwpeterson which link?

Comment: Welcome to MageOverflow, it would be great to just post comments with a link to http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store to help bringing specific answers for this to the problem.